# Phusion Passenger looking for wrong ruby path, how to change? *** Exception LoadError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner

Tags: redmine

I have RVM and it's default ruby is 2.0.0 
systemruby was 1.8.7 before and somehow my newly installed redmine 2.4.3 application tries to look for the old folder (1.8) instead of my 2.0.

That's my apache2 error log. :

```
*** Exception LoadError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (no such file to load -- bundler/setup)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /data/redmine2.4.3/redmine-2.4.3/config/boot.rb:6
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /data/redmine2.4.3/redmine-2.4.3/config/application.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /data/redmine2.4.3/redmine-2.4.3/config/environment.rb:2
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from config.ru:3
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1
```

I read that I can have different ruby setups in the apache2 config like this :

```
    PassengerRuby /home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    PassengerRoot /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.37
```

when I have set `AllowOverrid all`

What do I miss to make this work ?